# cudaMalloc fails with error: ** glibc detected **

Tags: cuda, glibc

I've been trying for a while to get cudaMalloc to work in NSight Eclipse but I am unable to get it to work in my own project. It works in the Cuda Sample: 'Vector Add' that I downloaded, compiled and ran fine however when I just copy and paste the following snippet into my function the same thing happens:

```
int numElements = 32;
size_t size = numElements * sizeof(float);
float *d_A = NULL;
assert(cudaMalloc((void **)&d_A, size) == cudaSuccess);
```

I am getting the following error after stepping over the cudaMalloc line:

```
*** glibc detected *** ... : free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000000c43080 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7eb96)[0x7f8f99bccb96]
/usr/lib/nvidia-current/libcuda.so(+0x770a1c)[0x7f8f9965aa1c]
/usr/lib/nvidia-current/libcuda.so(+0x770b6f)[0x7f8f9965ab6f]
/usr/lib/nvidia-current/libcuda.so(+0x268b7e)[0x7f8f99152b7e]
/usr/lib/nvidia-current/libcuda.so(+0x1b1a10)[0x7f8f9909ba10]
/usr/lib/nvidia-current/libcuda.so(+0xe7efd)[0x7f8f98fd1efd]
/usr/lib/nvidia-current/libcuda.so(cuInit+0x43)[0x7f8f98faa7d3]
...
```

NSight Debugger is also complaining that:

> Can't find a source file at "../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c" 
>   Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use cuda-memcheck to find the error. The debugger message "../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c" is there because you are getting exception in the system objects whose source is not there. If you provide entire code then can help more. Its most likely that you have corrupted some memory. Remember to use cudaFree and cudaDeviceReset in your code. *

Answer (score 2):

> however when I just copy and paste the following snippet into my function
>
> `*** glibc detected *** ... : free(): invalid next size`

There is nothing wrong with the code you showed. The problem is somewhere in *the rest* of your function (you've corrupted heap before the call to `cudaMalloc`).

Running your program under [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) is likely to point you straight at the bug.